# Converting a Parallel array to a Structure in C

Tags: c, arrays, parallel-processing, structure

I'm having tons of trouble converting a program that has a parallel array into a program that needs to be a structure.

Here is the original program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>

int  main ( void )

{

int num1,num2,sum,total=0,i;
int frequency[13]={0};
double expected[13] = {0,0,2.78,5.56,8.33,11.11,13.89,16.67,13.89,11.11,8.33,5.56,2.78};
double session[13]; 
int input=0;
int answer=1;



//ALGORITHM STEP 1:
 printf("\n This program will roll a die as many times as YOU choose.\n");

//ALGORITHM STEP 2:
while ( answer == 1 )
{ 
  printf("\n Please enter the number of times you would like to roll:");
  scanf("%d", &input);

//ALGORITHM STEP 3:
 srand(time(NULL));
 i=0;
 while( i<input )
{
 sum=0;
 num1=1+rand()%6;
 num2=1+rand()%6;
 sum=num1+num2;
 frequency[sum]++;
 i++;
 }

//ALGORITHM STEP 4:
 i=2;
 while( i<13 )
 {
 session[i]= ((double)frequency[i] / input)*100 ;
 i++;
 }

//ALGORITHM STEP 5:
 printf("\t Roll \t Session \t Expected \n ");
 i=2;
 while( i<13 )
{
 printf("\t%d   \t%2.2lf \t\t%2.2lf\n",i,session[i],expected[i]);
 i++;
}

//ALGORITHM STEP 6:
    printf("\n Would you like to enter another number?");
    printf("\n if so press 1 if not press 0: ");
    scanf("%d",&answer);
}

   printf(" Goodbye! \n");


 return ( 0 ) ;


}
```

I am at a loss. This is what I have so far, and I'm getting errors out the wazoo

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct dice
{
 int frequency[13];
 double expected[13];
 double session[13];
};


int  main ( void )

{

strcpy(dice_1.frequency,"0");
strcpy(dice_1.expected,"0,0,2.78,5.56,8.33,11.11,13.89,16.67,13.89,11.11,8.33,5.56,2.78");
strcpy(dice_1.session,"");


struct dice dice_1;
int num1,num2,sum,total=0,i;
int input=0;
int answer=1;

//ALGORITHM STEP 1:
 printf("\n This program will roll a die as many times as YOU choose.\n");

//ALGORITHM STEP 2:
while ( answer == 1 )
{
  printf("\n Please enter the number of times you would like to roll:");
  scanf("%d", &input);

//ALGORITHM STEP 3:
 srand(time(NULL));
 i=0;
 while( i<input )
{
 sum=0;
 num1=1+rand()%6;
 num2=1+rand()%6;
 sum=num1+num2;
 frequency[sum]++;
 i++;
}

//ALGORITHM STEP 4:
 i=2;
 while( i<13 )
 {
 session[i]= ((double)frequency[i] / input)*100 ;
 i++;
 }

//ALGORITHM STEP 5:
 printf("\t Roll \t Session \t Expected \n ");
 i=2;
 while( i<13 )
{
 printf("\t%d   \t%2.2lf \t\t%2.2lf\n",i,session[i],expected[i]);
 i++;
}

//ALGORITHM STEP 6:
    printf("\n Would you like to enter another number?");
    printf("\n if so press 1 if not press 0: ");
    scanf("%d",&answer);
}

   printf(" Goodbye! \n");


 return ( 0 ) ;


}
```

Comment: First step, declare your variables before you use them... Please spend some time actually reading your compiler's errors and warnings, they are actually useful.

Comment: I literally saw this *identical* problem (arrays, sizes, content, everything) a week ago. Damned if I can find it now. Event the algorithm *comment* tags were the same, so I harbor the suspicion it is the same class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this

```
int i=0;
char *token;
token = strtok(expected, ",");
while (token != NULL)
{
    switch(i)
    {
        case 0:
        //structure_object = your data;    change according to your requirement
        break;
        //continue until you have data to convert
    }
```

Please make sure data type must match for `int`, `double`, if it is string use `strcpy`.